# Can you use a lowercase letter after an apostrophe at the beginning of the sentence?

Tags: capitalization, apostrophe, dialogue

Let me start by saying that I'm aware you're *supposed* to capitalize the first letter after an apostrophe at the beginning of the sentence. My question is *can* I not. I have this inspiring piece of dialogue: “’kay" and I really much prefer it with the 'k' lowercase. Is that completely incorrect, or can I make the stylistic choice?

Comment: If it's a stylistic choice then we cannot argue. For example, authors have been known to omit punctuation altogether. My personal preference would be *'Kay*

Comment: I prefer your lowercase version too, although if this dialogue appeared in a nondramatic context I'd probably omit the apostrophe instead, so as to avoid an ugly clump of points at the beginning. If you're a grownup (more narrowly, if you're not getting graded on your punctuation) you can do whatever you want. If you're getting paid for your work, let your publisher worry about it.